# How do I fix Google reCapctha allowing my OpenCart registration even if it is not selected or validated

Tags: php, forms, validation, recaptcha, opencart2.3

I have an OpenCart registration form that uses Google reCaptcha. On the first time the form is submitted without selecting Google reCaptcha, the registration does not proceed. I am redirected back to the registration form with validation error on the reCaptca (as expected).

The form is re-submitted-this time, Google reCaptcha is selected (green check appears beside I'm not a robot). But some entries are not validated, e.g. passwords do not match. I am redirected back to the form with the validation errors (as expected).

This time, I make sure all entries are valid, but Google reCaptcha is not selected. The registration proceeded.

Is this a bug on Google reCaptcha? Is there any work around on this? Maybe set session or something?

Comment: follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8278827/entering-recaptcha-only-once-on-form-validation-fail. It may be helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out

Comment: The link recommends hiding the Google reCaptcha form. I'd prefer to keep the Google reCaptcha in display with the user having to go through the validation process. I tried grecaptcha.reset(), but the problem still remains

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by validating the form at the front end using JavaScript. The code I used is listed below:

```
var response = grecaptcha.getResponse();
if(response.length == 0){
    //prevent form from submitted, display alert to select reCaptcha
    return false;
}
//proceed with form submit
```

Comment: So the verification is only client-side? That seems ineffective.